# Why is "protested over" incorrect in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, phrasal-verbs

I've encountered another controversial sentence from the SAT writing section. Here it is:

> Given her strong sense of social justice, Burns vehemently **protested over** her party's failure to support a tax decrease for senior citizens.

Could anyone please explain why the highlighted part is wrong?

Comment: I think it's because it should be "...protested her party's failure...", rather than "...protested over her party's failure...".

Comment: British English needs a preposition (although omitting it is becoming more common). *Over* works in BrE; *about* would also work. Without a preposition, one might actually be arguing **for** whatever it is: *protest one's innocence,* for example.

Comment: *Over* works in AmE, too, as does *about*.  Leaving off a preposition works most of the time, but occasionally it does not seem to work.  If the SAT objects to "over" then I can't fathom why.

Comment: I would have said 'protested at her party's failure...'.If you leave out the preposition altogether it is a bit like 'protesting one's innocence'. The verb is suddenly transitive, and it doesn't make sense in the case the OP quotes. I also think the fashion for 'over' is equally ridiculous. One 'looks over' and one is 'sick over' something or someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my ear, the preposition after *protested* sounds strange. I searched the NYT for similar phrases, finding:

> - was ejected in the eighth inning of their 14-inning 9-5 victory after he *vehemently protested an overturned call* at first base.
> - ...failed in his fiduciary obligations and had put personal and family gain ahead of union interests — judgments that he *vehemently protested*.
> - ... Ms. Winston said *she vehemently protested* that idea. ''My suggestion to Van was that CBS rethink...
> - students have frequently rebelled; in 2008, *they protested* what they described as slipping academic requirements, shoddy...
> - More than 230 people were arrested yesterday in San Francisco as *they protested* President Reagan's Central America policy...

But I was unable to fine even one instance of *he vehemently protested over*, and very few *protested + over* in any context (in the NYT).

Answer (score 0):

When used as a noun:

> The protest over (or about) this SAT question is still ongoing.

When used as a verb:

> Vlad protested against the answers to this question.

Therefore:

> Given her strong sense of social justice, Burns vehemently protested
>   against her party's failure to support a tax decrease for senior
>   citizens.

Comment: To my thinking, the word *protested* already carried *against* (publicly demonstrate *strong objection* to a policy or course of action adopted by those in authority) and saying it is needless. She is protesting her party's failure.